# problems in a good topology (subdivision)

Tags: topology

According to one coach, the topology is impeccable.
Is it possible to correct these depressions by **improving the topology**?
At different subdivision levels, distortions look different.

The [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJ0BsatjB91afLSrb5Z31OuFh6NF84HI/view?usp=sharing).

thank you

[image]

Comment: I agree with your coach, the topology is good, it looks bad because of the particular shading you've chosen but the render should be ok

Comment: @moonboots
>>it looks bad because of the particular shading

________________________________________________________

it is a matcap

Comment: Yes I meant the matcap shading

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure why you wanna have a subdiv modifier - but what about using a bevel modifier instead?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't totally agree with your coach, but I'm no topology expert. Feel free to contradict me if I say something wrong.

The pinching you are experiencing is due to the diagonal edge being longer than the 2 adjacent edges. It streches the surface along the diagonal. On the right side is an exagerated version to visualize the issue.

[image: Comparison of different pinching]

You can move the vertex along the edges by pressing <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and moving the cursor.

At most, the diagonal should probably be the same length as the 2 surrounding edges. With a bit of testing, I would even suggest giving the diagonal edge a smaller length (as in my screenshot or even less).